# Send XML File through httpRequest using Genexus 17

Tags: java, web, xmlhttprequest, genexus

I am trying to send a XML path in a httprequest.
I try in different ways and none works.
My last try was:

```
&Httpclient.Addheader("Content-Type", !"multipart/form-data")
&httpclient.AddVariable('idEmpresa', '123')
&httpclient.AddVariable('senha','abcdfg')
&HttpClient.AddFile('file','.\dadosConciliadora_27-01-2023_09h24m09s697ms.xml')
&HttpClient.Execute(httpmethod.Post, &url)
```

The message is always "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
Application is based in Java.

I trying send a XML file to a API.

Comment: AddFile method has FullPath and FileName parameters (https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?7046,AddFile+method).
I think you have them reversed (name, path).

Anyway you could include more information about the error: it's an error when specifying the object within the IDE (Genexus Log could be useful) or it's a runtime error (Java log could be useful)

Comment: I change de parameters and works, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

&HttpClient.AddFile('.\dadosConciliadora_27-01-2023_09h24m09s697ms.xml','file')

This resolve the problem.